# Right way of testing service used by controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, tdd

Given the code below:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def create
    if auth_is_alright && params_are_cool #pseudocode
      @bar_results = BarService.new(param).run
    end
  end
end

class BarService
  def initialize(params)
    @transaction_token = params[:transaction_token]
    @id = params[:id]
    @quantity = params[:quantity]
    @value = params[:value]
    if Transaction.where(token: @transaction_token).any?
      _undo_previous_run    
    end
  end

  def run
    Transaction.new(token: @transaction_token, product_id: @id, quantity: @quantity, value: @value).save!
    product = Product.find(id: @id)
    product.update!(stock_quantity: product.stock_quantity - @quantity)
  end

private

  def _undo_previous_run
    transaction = Transaction.find_by_token(@transaction_token)
    product = Product.find(id: transaction.product_id)
    product.update!(stock_quantity: product.stock_quantity + transaction.quantity)
    transaction.destroy
  end

end
```

Now my question is, where should be the right place to test _undo_previous_run behavior?:

- BarServiceSpec?
- FooControllerSpec? (calling the create action and etc)
- Others?

Answer (score 1):

Tests are usually used like "documentation" for class API. `_undo_previous_run` is private method and can not be directly accessed. I prefer to test/describe behavior of public methods.

In that case you need to test `BarService.new` method.

Comment: Wouldn't you consider to test it more "externally", like in the FooControllerSpec, calling the create action with the same params twice and checking the outcome of it? If not, why?

Comment: If your goal is to ensure same return value after each call than that is a good approach. You need to write as less tests as you can, but enough to cover all valuable functionality. For `BarService.new` I'll write next tests: for setting each instance variable; updating `stock_quantity` for `product`; removing `transaction` with token (if exists).